# Pipeline Datapaths

Tags: computer-science, pipeline, cpu-architecture

I'm studying a "Pipeline Datapaths" lesson and I have found these three terms "sign-extended offset,branch address,Zero signal" regarding to pipe line registers ID/EX and ID/MEM but I have no any idea about those three. Can any one simply explain those three terms. It is difficult to get simple idea from the web because I'm just a beginner.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

They are all related to the I-type MIPS branch instruction, which compares the value of one or 2 registers and branches if they are/aren't equal.

The MIPS PC is 32 bit long, but the branch instruction has only a 16 bit relative address. Those 2 need to be added together to calculate the new PC value in case of a branch. For this the 16 bit address is expanded to 32 bit ( sign extend + shift to the left 2 positions ).

This is the **sign-extended offset** which is then added to the current PC to get the target address ( the **branch address** ).

The branch condition is checked by the ALU unit and it will assert the **zero signal** if needed.
This zero signal is then gated by a branch signal from the control unit and those 2 control the mux that selects the new value that will be written into the PC.

If the zero signal is one and the current instruction is a branch instruction then the PC will be loaded with the calculated branch address, else PC +4.

Comment: Thank you for your answer and can you point me to good tutorial which describes how single cycle datapath works.

Comment: Try these two [Link](http://www.cise.ufl.edu/~mssz/CompOrg/CDA-proc.html) [Link](http://www.cise.ufl.edu/~mssz/CompOrg/CDA-pipe.html)